# MIP binary variable value based on value of continuous variable

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to model the following constraint:
$$ 
b = 
    \begin{cases}
    1 \quad \text{if } c=0 \\
    0 \quad \text{if } c>0 \\
    \end{cases},
$$
where $b\in\{0,1\}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.

The context of this problem: $c$ represents the idle time between two successive operations on a machine. Instead of capturing the duration of this idle time, I would only like to know whether there was idle time ($b=1$) or not ($b=0$).

So far, I only found related posts that assume that $c$ is a binary variable as well, see e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp).

**Edit:**

In case I know that $c\leq C$ and given that I maximize over $b$, I can express this by the single constraint
$$
b\leq (1-\frac{c}{C}).
$$
To see this:

- In case $c=0$, we get $b\leq 1$. Since we maximize, this will lead to $b=1$.
- In case $c>0$, we get that $0\leq b<1$, which is only satisfied for $b=0$.

**Question:**

However, is there also a way to model this constraint without implicitly using the fact that we maximize over $b$ and without using an upperbound $C$ on $c$?

Comment: Maybe we can find other ways to formulate the constraints if you can explain the complete problem

Comment: @cbs Thank you for the suggestion, but I really like to find an answer to this particular question.

Comment: I thought I had found the answer in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83856/expressing-conditional-in-linear-program?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, but that only seems to work if $c$ is integer valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the strict inequality causes problems, meaning you cannot model what you want exactly (using linear constraints and binary variables). There are two approaches that may come close enough, depending on context. Both require a valid upper bound $C$ for $c$.

First, $0\le c \le C(1-b)$. If $c>0$, this forces $b=0$ as desired. If $c=0$, though, both $b=0$ and $b=1$ satisfy the constraint.

Alternatively, $\epsilon (1-b) \le c \le C(1-b)$ with $\epsilon > 0$ a small constant enforces $c = 0 \implies b=1$ and $c\ge \epsilon \implies b=0$. Unfortunately, it renders $0 < c < \epsilon$ infeasible. When using this approach, it is tempting to pick a really, really tiny positive value for $\epsilon$, but that will not work due to rounding problems (it will look like 0 to the solver and put you back in the first case).

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. Actually, I came to the same solution as the second one that you propose. Since I am maximizing over $b$, it may happen that unnecessary idle time (see context in the question) may arise so that the corresponding value of $b$ for that idle period equals $1$. However, this is not a problem in case $\epsilon$ is even like 0.1, because I am scheduling jobs whose durations are most often >10 (minutes). In practice this unnecessary idle time does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

The set
$$
\{(b,c) \mid b \in \{0,1\} \land \text{"your condition"}\}$$
is not closed. Hence, it is not possible to model it as a 'nice' constraint.

Comment: I see what you mean, it is because the value of $c$ can get arbitrarily close to 0. I wonder how to deal with such a constraint then. Probably I need to model it in a more implicit way.