# Conditional modelling of a binary variable based on the values of two continous variables

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, mixed-integer-programming

I want to model a binary variable $(b)$ from two continous variables $(x_{in},\:x_{out})$.

These variables are $ 0\leq x_{in} \leq x_{max},\: 0\leq x_{out} \leq x_{max})$. I want the following three conditions to apply on my binary variable

$$Condition\:1: b=1\:if\: x_{in}>0\:and\:x_{out}=0\\
Condition\:2: b=0\:if\: x_{in}=0\:and\:x_{out}>0\\
Condition\:3: b=0\:if\: x_{in}=0\:and\:x_{out}=0$$

I have tried two methods and neither of them worked.

**First method**

Method is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914193/linear-programming-purely-linear-formulation-lp-for-the-expression-if-x-0).
$$x_{in}=b \times x_{max}$$
$$x_{out}=(1-b) \times x_{max}$$
The above solution works for the first two condition but it doesn't work for the 3rd condition.

**Second method**

Method is explained under [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281875/mip-binary-variable-value-based-on-value-of-continuous-variable) discussion.
$$\epsilon\times b \leq x_{in} \leq \epsilon\times b \times x_{max}\\
\epsilon\times b \leq x_{out} \leq \epsilon\times b \times x_{max}$$
where $\epsilon>0$ and it is a very small number $(e.g. 10^{-9})$.

I am using most recent version of Gurobi.

Can you please help?
I have tried everything (that I could understand from forums). My knowledge of optimisation algorithms is limited so I apologise in advance if this question is duplicate.

Comment: Do you care what value $b$ takes if both $x_{\text{in}}>0$ and $x_{\text{out}}>0$?

Comment: @RobPratt no i don't.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that conditions 2 and 3 can be merged as: $b=0$ if $x_\text{in}=0$.  You want to enforce
\begin{align}
(x_\text{in} > 0 \land x_\text{out} = 0) &\implies b=1 \\
x_\text{in} = 0 &\implies b=0 
\end{align}
Equivalently, you want to enforce their contrapositives
\begin{align}
b=0 &\implies (x_\text{in} = 0 \lor x_\text{out} > 0) \\
b=1 &\implies x_\text{in} > 0
\end{align}
Equivalently, introduce binary variables $c$ and $d$ and enforce
\begin{align}
b=0 &\implies (c = 1 \lor d = 1) \\
c=1 &\implies x_\text{in} = 0 \\
d=1 &\implies x_\text{out} > 0 \\
b=1 &\implies x_\text{in} > 0 
\end{align}
Now replace $>0 $ with $\ge \epsilon$, and you obtain linear constraints
\begin{align}
1 - b &\le c + d \\
x_\text{in} &\le x_\text{max}(1-c) \\
x_\text{out} &\ge \epsilon d \\
x_\text{in} &\ge \epsilon b
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your conditions, it is sufficient to introduce the following formulations

b <= M x X_in ; ( where M is a constant number greater than X_max )

b >= epsilon x ( X_in - X_out )

b in {0,1}

in this manner and due to the above formulations and

Condition 1: we have b<=M and b>=(epsilon). Hence, b=1.

Condition 2: we have b<=0 and b>=(-epsilon). Hence, b=0.

Condition 3: we have b<=0 and b>=0. Hence, b=0.

Good luck

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your second constraint is too restrictive because the RHS can be as large as $x_\max$, which might be more than $1$.

Comment: You are right and I did a mistake to write the second constraint and I should write    b >= epsilon x ( X_in - X_out )